# Loopback Post API error

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm just learn about Loopback from StrongLoop to create a simple API.

I got some trouble to make the API works.

Here is my config :

```
model.js
--------
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Account) {

};
```

This is my model.json:

```
{
  "name": "Account",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "defaultFn": "uuidv4",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "id",
        "dataType": "uuid"
      }
    },
    "code": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "code",
        "dataType": "character varying",
        "dataLength": "50"
      }
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "name",
        "dataType": "text"
      }
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "type",
        "dataType": "character varying",
        "dataLength": "50"
      }
    },
    "isActive": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "default": true
    },
    "isDelete": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "default": false
    },
    "createdBy": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "defaultFn": "uuidv4",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "createdBy",
        "dataType": "uuid"
      }
    },
    "updatedBy": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "defaultFn": "uuidv4",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "updatedBy",
        "dataType": "uuid"
      }
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "defaultFn": "now"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
      "type": "date",
      "required": true,
      "defaultFn": "now"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

The following model have been migrated successfull, I'm using postgresql for my db.

The problem is when Loopback create the CRUD standard API, the POST API seem to not working when I try the POST method. below is my json string when i try to put on API explorer :

```
{
    "id": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000",
    "code": "1000",
    "name": "Cash and Bank",
    "type": "Assets",
    "isActive": true,
    "isDelete": false,
    "createdBy": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000",
    "updatedBy": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000",
    "createdAt": "2017-09-01T17:00:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-09-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  }
```

But It throw an error, here is the response body :

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "error",
    "message": "syntax error at end of input",
    "length": 92,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42601",
    "position": "230",
    "file": "scan.l",
    "line": "1078",
    "routine": "scanner_yyerror",
    "stack": "error: syntax error at end of input\n    at Connection.parseE (/media/andylpjr/EA7C669F7C6665F3/Project/kpost/kpost-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:567:11)\n    at Connection.parseMessage (/media/andylpjr/EA7C669F7C6665F3/Project/kpost/kpost-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:391:17)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/andylpjr/EA7C669F7C6665F3/Project/kpost/kpost-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)\n    at TCP.onread (net.js:561:20)"
  }
}
```

For the note when I'm try from the pgadmin insert to table using SQL query it works. Something like "INSERT INTO Account VALUES (bla bla bla)". I know this maybe just a common mistake, please help. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Well case closed, it appears I'm missing my model definition for primary key, what a shame.. Thanks guys.